# PyCharm 3.2 issue: the packages are listed in External Libraries but unsolved in editor

Tags: python, pycharm

#### Background

I've been using PyCharm with Conda for up to two years, but until a week ago, it was performing normally. But after I use python 3.10 virtual environment once, the following problem happens in any environment(3.8; 3.9; local and origin). However, the code runs successfully and everything works fine in VSCode.

#### Description

The editor shows 'unsolved package xxx', but the package has shown in 'External Libraries'.

[image: screenshot of PyCharm problem]

After my observation, it seems to be unable to solve models that are imported in any `__init__` file. If no `__init__`, it will solve successfully (like Adam in torch.optim).

[image]

#### I have already tried followings:

1. File -> repire IDE
2. File -> Invalidate caches
3. Reinstall; Install EAP; Install Pycharm 3.1
4. Reinstall conda environment

But the issue still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `__init__.py` from **Preferences | Editor | File Types | File type auto-detected by file content | File name patterns**

[image]

You were likely tricked by the obscure UI to add it (see the corresponding ticket in JetBrains issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284056). The UX will be tweaked in 2022.1 release to prevent this from happening.

Comment: This solved my problem very well, thank you very much.

Comment: @pavel-karateev  You are an absolute hero to me! I've been searching all over for a solution to solve my Pycharm package indexing issues. Packages were installed correctly and the interpreter was great, the code ran successfully but for a long time my IDE kept on showing unresolved resources for modules within a an installed package. 
Again, the error was only on the module, for example from a import b - the IDE manage to detect a but flagged an error on b. No suggestion from the IDE regarding inner modules, functions.. nothing.
This was the ONLY solution that helped so thanks a lot!!